# redirect home page to AMP (accelerated mobile page) on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, amp-html

I wrote a php script to point my Wordpress home page to an amp page, but it doesn't work on all mobile devices. I don't want to redirect any other page, just the home page. Also, the theme uses javascript to identify mobile devices, so I'm not sure if that is conflicting with the php script. See both below.

Is there is a way to use htaccess to redirect the home page only to the AMP page, thus avoiding any javascript compatibility issues?

---

Javascript

```
<script>
function detectmob() {
    if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
    ){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
if ( is_page( 2256 ) ) {
    if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
        $url = "https://mywebsite.com/amp/index.amp.html";
        wp_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: As long as you have the above redirect before _any_ output (not even a single line break/space), it should work. Even if you have javascript on that page, it will never be loaded so there can't be any sort of conflict.

Comment: That is very interesting, Magnus. I did, in fact, have a single line break between the javascript and the php. It's also immediately before doctype html script.

Comment: Now I'm confused, do you first have the JavaScript, then the PHP and then the HTML? Either way, the PHP must be the absolute first in the file. JavaScript should generally also be either in the `<head>` or the `<body>`-section.

Comment: Yes, the PHP is under the javascript. I'll move the PHP to the top, per your suggestion. You are right; the javascript does not need to preceed the doctype script. Thank  you for your fresh set of eye on this issue!